# Is it wise to use laravel jobs to upload videos?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to have the possibility to upload videos, but unfortunately, the process of uploading takes too long and I want to either show a spinner or to do the upload part in the background. Since it's PHP, the first option is not viable. So the only solution I see is to use Laravel Queues, are there others? Is it ok to use Laravel Queues for what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your view on frontend/backend and background jobs is not correct.

Background jobs in laravel are long running jobs, started by Laravel, but inaccessible to your users (you cannot use it for uploads).

What you need in the case of a large upload is to split the file in the frontend, and upload these chunks to the server. These are small parts. Later you use a background job to combine the chunks to one file again.

This does mean you need a JavaScript frontend to split the file, could be Vue, could be Vanilla JavaScript.

In one of my systems I have the following:

1. Frontend send request to backend to start a chunk session, sending original file name, size and full file hash.
2. Backend saves request info, returns info on hope many parts are to be uploaded and of what size.
3. Frontend starts upload process, splitting the file in parts.
4. When all parts are uploaded, frontend send finalize call to server.
5. Server starts background job, combining all the parts, checking if combined file matches original file hash. When done, chunk session is marked as done, update is broadcasted to frontend (websockets)
6. Frontend could also simply pull the info of chunk session in use to check if background job is done.
7. Frontend requests backend to `use` the uploaded file. For example, storing the file somewhere now involves a call to the backend with the chunk session information instead of a file upload of course.

This all works quite fast, combining the chunks is a very fast process. And it makes it possible to allow gigabyte uploads in my case. You will need knowledge on file splitting in JavaScript and using file streams in PHP to combine the parts.